# Making a function use std::span instead of the old way

Tags: c++, std, c++20

I just learned that I could use VS 2019 with C++ 20 and I'm trying to make use of it. I'm trying to make the following function use `std::span`, because that way `data_size` and `key_size` would be redundant.

Everything is alright except `*data` and `data++`. What is it supposed to be?

```cpp
int rc4(rc4_context* context, const std::uint8_t* data, const std::size_t data_size, const std::uint8_t* key, const std::size_t key_size, std::uint8_t* output)
{
    std::uint32_t i, j;

    // Check parameters
    if (!context || !key)
        return ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER;

    // Clear context
    context->i = 0;
    context->j = 0;

    // Initialize the S array with identity permutation
    for (i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        context->s[i] = static_cast<std::uint8_t>(i);
    }

    // S is then processed for 256 iterations
    for (i = 0, j = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        // Randomize the permutations using the supplied key
        j = (j + context->s[i] + key[i % key_size]) % 256;

        // Swap the values of S[i] and S[j]
        const auto temp = context->s[i];
        context->s[i] = context->s[j];
        context->s[j] = temp;
    }

    // Restore context
    i = context->i;
    j = context->j;
    auto* s = context->s;

    // Encryption loop
    for (size_t x = 0; x < data_size; ++x)
    {
        // Adjust indices
        i = (i + 1) % 256;
        j = (j + s[i]) % 256;

        // Swap the values of S[i] and S[j]
        const auto temp = s[i];
        s[i] = s[j];
        s[j] = temp;

        // Valid input and output?
        if (data && output)
        {
            // XOR the input data with the RC4 stream
            *output = *data ^ s[(s[i] + s[j]) % 256];

            // Increment data pointers
            data++;
            output++;
        }
    }

    // Save context
    context->i = i;
    context->j = j;

    return NO_ERROR;
}
```

#### My attempt

```cpp
int rc4(rc4_context* context, const std::span<uint8_t*> data, const std::span<std::uint8_t*> key, std::uint8_t* output)
{
    // INITIALIZATION
    std::uint32_t i, j;

    // Check parameters
    if (!context || !key.empty())
        return ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER;

    // Clear context
    context->i = 0;
    context->j = 0;

    // Initialize the S array with identity permutation
    for (i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        context->s[i] = static_cast<std::uint8_t>(i);
    }

    // S is then processed for 256 iterations
    for (i = 0, j = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        // Randomize the permutations using the supplied key
        j = (j + context->s[i] + key[i % key.size()]) % 256;

        // Swap the values of S[i] and S[j]
        const auto temp = context->s[i];
        context->s[i] = context->s[j];
        context->s[j] = temp;
    }

    // MAIN LOGIC PART
    // Restore context
    i = context->i;
    j = context->j;
    auto* s = context->s;

    // Encryption loop
    for (size_t x = 0; x < data.size(); ++x)
    {
        // Adjust indices
        i = (i + 1) % 256;
        j = (j + s[i]) % 256;

        // Swap the values of S[i] and S[j]
        const auto temp = s[i];
        s[i] = s[j];
        s[j] = temp;

        // Valid input and output?
        if (data.empty() && output)
        {
            // XOR the input data with the RC4 stream
            *output = *data ^ s[(s[i] + s[j]) % 256];

            // Increment data pointers
            data++;
            output++;
        }
    }

    // Save context
    context->i = i;
    context->j = j;

    return NO_ERROR;
}
```

Comment: `std::span<uint8_t*>` -> `std::span<uint8_t>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, the pair of parameters `(const std::uint8_t* data, const std::size_t data_size)` can be replaced by `std::span<uint8_t>`, not `std::span<uint8_t*>`.

Second, you don't need to bother incrementing `data` since you can rewrite this to be a range-based for loop:

```cpp
for (uint8_t elem : data) {
    // Adjust indices
    i = (i + 1) % 256;
    j = (j + s[i]) % 256;    

    // Swap the values of S[i] and S[j]
    std::swap(s[i], s[j]);

    // Valid output?
    if (output) {
        // XOR the input data with the RC4 stream
        *output++ = elem ^ s[(s[i] + s[j]) % 256];
    }   
}
```

Comment: @nop You don't need to construct all the arguments up front, you can just pass the array and the vector into your function directly: `rc4(&context, log_data, key, result)`. Is `log_size` not just `log_data.size()`, seems like it doesn't need to be an extra call. `const auto& result = new uint8_t[log_size];` is very suspect, either wrap that in `unique_ptr` or use a `vector` so that you get your memory managed.

Comment: Only `log_data` doesn't want to be passed directly. `Cannot convert lvalue of type const std::vector<std::byte> to parameter type std::span<uint8_t>`. This is the read_log_file function https://pastebin.com/2Vp6TL0M

Comment: @nop Just change it to be a `vector<uint8_t>`? If you need `uint8_t`, you need `uint8_t`...

Comment: This *could* be `std::ranges::copy(data, output, [](std::uint8_t elem) { /* body of loop with return instead of assign */ });`